# Angular | Shared modules between different projects

Tags: angular, web-component

I have 4 angular projects which share the same angular library and changing the library means that I have deploy all the 4 projects individually.

Was wondering if I can use angular web components to dynamically load the library via a given url ? or some other solution so that I don't have to deploy the projects individually.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to see if you can load component library via CDN

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new repo with shared modules and place it on version control platforms such as github. let's say your shared module repo is `github.com/ninja420/angular-shared`

Then you can include it into package.json of each project repo.

```
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "@ninja420/shared": "git+ssh://git@github.com:ninja420/angular-shared.git#master",
  ...
}
```

And you can import the shared modules into project modules:

```
import { SharedModule } from '@ninja420/shared';

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can bump version tags on shared module repo when you updated something like:

```
"@ninja420/shared": "git+ssh://git@github.com:ninja420/angular-shared.git#v1.0.1"
```

Comment: This is what we do right now, we will still need to deploy them individually right ?

Comment: yes but bumping versions on individual repos are not technically renewing the deployment.